# Can an existing synchronous function call be replaced with one relying on async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to replace an existing function call with one that calls out to parent frame PostMessage and receives another related PostMessage message back with a value.

I am trying to have as little disruption to existing code as possible since there are a couple hundred lines where it is called.

---

Current code is like the following...

```
function thisfunc(){
  return checksomethingincurrentpage()
}

if(thisfunc() == 'something')
    // do something

// do something else
```

When switched to be based on PostMessage send/receive from parent fraome, can thisfunc() one way or another not return until the corresponding PostMessage is received and do so in the same execution path?

I was trying something like this but does not look like it works. (I don't have the test code anymore)

```
//pseudocode...

resolvefunc = null;

function getprom()
  prom = new promise 
    set resolvingfunc equal to resolve function
  postmessagecall;
  return prom;

async function thisfunc()
  response = await getprom();
  return response;

eventListener for post message
  receive post message
  resolvefunc(postmessagepayload)

if(thisfunc() == 'something')
  // something
```

I saw that XMLHttpRequest could be made to be synchronous but doesn't help in this case with PostMessage.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: No it cannot. The best it can do is return a promise but then the caller has to handle the promise accordingly. If the `if` statement is in a function you could make it async and do  `if (await thisfunc() === 'something') { ... }`.

Comment: @FelixKling so the only possible option is a chain of callback? Of course making that change in existing codebase would be a lot of work so trying to avoid. I understand if not possible. I'm trying a "sleep" approach now using loop but I believe that might block processing of postmessage event... ?

Comment: Yes, if you actively block the thread then nothing will work. I wouldn't call it a callback chain though. With async/await, promises can be handled fairly transparently. Of course I don't know what your codebase look like, but adding `await` where necessary might be doable?

Comment: @FelixKling my understanding is that await only works inside async function so would require making the parent asynchronous. I don't think that would work for us in most cases but I'll review the situations where it would be needed.

Comment: @DanRoberts Everything that wants to use `postMessage` and wait for a response **becomes** asynchronous by definition. Regardless how deep in the call stack that it is hidden.

Comment: is there a capability in newer javascript versions to do something similar to what I am attempting to do that could be transpiled? I'm currently looking at adjusting all our code for async approach but wanted to check.

Comment: No there isn't.